Unable to record audio in GCP debian VM
I have been stuck to record audio in a debian vitual machine. uname -a gives: configuration is - 5.10.0-31-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.221-1 (2024-07-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux. I have installed pulse audio, pavucontrol, alsa(all installations), sox.

With aplay -l, it displays no sound cards are available. I followed the solution on this link-https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082472/how-can-i-resolve-this-problem-unable-to-locate-package-linux-image-extra-4-15 .
But on running this command-sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual
i get error- E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-extra-5.10.0-31-cloud-amd64 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-modules-extra-5.10.0-31-cloud-amd64' E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-virtual

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434488/modprobe-fatal-module-snd-aloop-not-found-linstall-inux-modules-extra-5-4-0
sudo modprobe snd-gives-modprobe: FATAL: Module snd not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.0-31-cloud-amd64
on running- sudo apt install linux-generic
i get-E: Unable to locate package linux-generic

https://askubuntu.com/questions/70560/why-am-i-getting-this-connection-to-pulseaudio-failed-error
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install pulseaudio
autospawn = yes

on trying any pulse audio command- i get connection refused error.


The issue still remains unresolved. Please let me know if there is any possible solution. Thanks in advance.

Ensure that your virtual machine has a virtual sound card enabled, check this blog.

Hi @SaiChandraGadde, i have a debian os and these virtual sound cards are for windows and mac.

Try below commands for pulse audio and let me know if you are facing an error attach the output in the question :
$ sudo glinux-config set audio_server pulseaudio
$ sudo glinux-updater
$ sudo reboot

Another solution worth trying
systemctl --user restart pipewire
systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse


Hi Sai - for the first glinux-config command i got this error :sudo: glinux-updater: command not found and for the systemctl command i got this error:Failed to restart pipewire.service: Unit pipewire.service not found.
